# Where does the JVM.dll search for dependent dll's

Tags: java, dll

The java JVM.dll uses in certain environments the MS dll MSVCR71.dll.   When looking for this resource, does the JVM.dll look for it in certain locations in a proscribed order.  For example, does it look for it in the current directory first, then some system directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses [a documented search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to look for DLLs – Java probably uses that for the C runtime. (Any process may otherwise load a DLL from an arbitrary path in the filesystem security restrictions notwithstanding, but I don't believe this is the case.)